# forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, efficientnet

I'm trying to build a Model using EfficientNet-B0.
The details of the Model are shown in the code below.
I got the following error when I tried to learn.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
'''
<ipython-input-17-fb3850894108> in forward(self, *x)
     24         #x: bs*N x 3 x 128 x 128
     25         print(x.shape)     #([384, 3, 224, 224])
---> 26         x = self.enc(x)
     27         #x: bs*N x C x 4 x 4
     28         shape = x.shape

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
     98     def forward(self, input):
     99         for module in self:
--> 100             input = module(input)
    101         return input
    102 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

TypeError: forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I suspect that m.children() may have an effect.
If anyone knows the cause of this error, please let me know.
Thank you.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, arch='efficientnet-b0', n=6, pre=True):
        super().__init__()
        m = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b0')
        #print(*list(m.children())
        nc = m._fc.in_features
        print(nc)
        self.enc = nn.Sequential(*list(m.children())[:-2])
        #nc = list(m.children())[-2].in_features
        self.head = nn.Sequential(*list(m.children())[-2:])
        self.head._fc = nn.Linear(nc, n)
        #self.enc = nn.Sequential(*list(m.children()))
        #print('fc_infeatures : {}'.format(nc))
        #self.head = nn.Sequential(Flatten(),nn.Linear(nc,512),
        #                    relu(),nn.BatchNorm1d(512), nn.Dropout(0.5),nn.Linear(512,n))


    def forward(self, *x):
        print(x[0].shape)  #([32, 3, 224, 224])
        shape = x[0].shape
        n = len(x)           # n = 12
        #torch.stack直後では32*12*3*224*224(bs x N x 3 x 224 x 224)
        x = torch.stack(x,1).view(-1,shape[-3],shape[-2],shape[-1])
        #x: bs*N x 3 x 128 x 128
        print(x.shape)     #([384, 3, 224, 224])
        x = self.enc(x)
        #x: bs*N x C x 4 x 4
        shape = x.shape
        #concatenate the output for tiles into a single map
        x = x.view(-1,n,shape[1],shape[2],shape[3]).permute(0,2,1,3,4).contiguous()\
          .view(-1,shape[1],shape[2]*n,shape[3])
        #x: bs x C x N*4 x 4
        x = self.head(x)
        return x
```

Comment: adding the asterisk in `forward(self, *x)` unpacks the list `x`. You should remove it

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/iafoss/panda-concat-tile-pooling-starter-0-79-lb
This kernel is able to run using ResNet. I don't think it's necessary to take an asterisk because I'm inputting a tuple. Please let me know if I can figure out the cause.

Comment: Paste the code section where you use an instance of the `Model` class.

Comment: Thank you for contacting us, as a Model we have transferred learning based on this.

https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/blob/master/efficientnet_pytorch/model.py

Answer (score 2):

[Now](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/pull/208) you can easily get the network without the last layers by using the *include_top* parameter:

```
m = EfficientNet.from_pretrained('efficientnet-b0', include_top=False)
```

What it does, as can be easily seen [in the code](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/pull/208/commits/f522b18077d4e488f88d0662eebcb0d5a4843b99), is not calling forward method for the last layers (AveragePool, Dropout, FC).

Other [alternative approaches](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/issues/207) can be summarized as followings:

1. Define a new MyEfficientNet that **override the forward method** to avoid calling the last layers
2. **Overwrite the layers** you don't need with an identity layer. For example:

   m._fc = nn.Identity()

The first approach should be preferred when using the efficientnet as a features extractor while the others should be used when more customisation is needed.